# ImmediateFlush not working in Log4j2

Tags: java, asynchronous, logging, log4j2, catalina.out

I am getting this error:

> ERROR asyncRoot contains an invalid element or attribute "immediateFlush"

When I use immediateFlush attribute in appender in log4j2.xml.

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss} [$${ctx:instId} - $${ctx:userId}] %c.%M(%L)- %m%n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="csroot"
        fileName="${cslogs}/cslog.log" filePattern="${cslogs}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/cslog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss} [$${ctx:instId} - $${ctx:userId}] %c.%M(%L)- %m%n" immediateFlush="false"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1000">
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your `log4j2.xml` configuration file here

Comment: i have posted that part in my qquestion now

Answer (score 4):

Try with this modification:

```
<RollingFile name="csroot"
    fileName="${cslogs}/cslog.log" filePattern="${cslogs}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/cslog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" immediateFlush="false">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss} [$${ctx:instId} - $${ctx:userId}] %c.%M(%L)- %m%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1000">
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
```

`immediateFlush` is not an attribute of `PatternLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

I know its quite an old question but might help somebody.
[RollingFile Appender Parameters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) points out the `immediateFlush` is the property of the appender. But you have it declared as an attribute for `PatternLayout` which is what is causing the error.

---

Sample RollingFile appender configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                 immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```